# How to listen for iOS notifications and get the content of them?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I know this is a long shot, but I saw an app that reads allowed the person who has just sent you a text, so you don't have to check who the message is from. I want to know if there is a way to listen for any notifications on the phone, and if a notification has appeared, get the title and the text of that notification.

For example, I launch the app, turn 'listening' on, then when I get a notification from another app, it is listening for notifications so it picks it up and logs it to the command line.

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, so I am asking it here. Thanks!

Comment: no, it is not possible